# All Possible combination for an HEX Value from a given set of chars

Tags: python, dataset, hex, subtraction

I am looking for a code, or a sample code that can have a predefined set of hex values and that can find the 3 used values within to generate a certain value.

let's say I have a value of : 0x50158A51

this is a 4 byte (32 bit) hex value

now i need to find the values which when added or subtracted (from the provided set)  will end with this result.

for example:

0x75612171 + 0x75612171 + 0x6553476F = 0x50158A51

- notice that the values added are all from the allowed set

Just to be clear i have a limited chars set

which is :

```
\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13
\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f\x20\x21\x22\x23\x24\x25\x26
\x27\x28\x29\x2a\x2b\x2c\x2d\x2e\x2f\x30\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39
\x3a\x3b\x3c\x3d\x3e\x3f\x40\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46\x47\x48\x49\x4a\x4b\x4c
\x4d\x4e\x4f\x50\x51\x52\x53\x54\x55\x56\x57\x58\x59\x5a\x5b\x5c\x5d\x5e\x5f
\x60\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66\x67\x68\x69\x6a\x6b\x6c\x6d\x6e\x6f\x70\x71\x72
\x73\x74\x75\x76\x77\x78\x79\x7a\x7b\x7c\x7d\x7e\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85
\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98
\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab
\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe
\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1 
\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4 
\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7 
\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff
```

i used a simple code to calculate 3 values:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

hex1 = 0x55555521
hex2 = 0x55555421
hex3 = 0x6D556F49

calc = hex1 + hex2 + hex3
print hex(calc)
```

which will give a result of:

```
root@linux:~# ./calc2.py
0x150158a51
```

i need to some how reverse the process of the answer by placing variations from my allowed set into the variables

for example:

placing 4 byte hex values from the set into the variables

```
 try: 

hex1 = placing 4bytes from allowed set
hex2 = placing 4bytes from allowed set
hex3 = placing 4bytes from allowed set

if result (hex1+hex2+hex3)  = 0x150158a51
then
print "values used for this results are: hex1 hex2 hex3"
```

Comment: You may want to mark this one as homework (it sounds like that)

Comment: Your problem description is unclear.  Chars do not exist in python except as elements of strings, which cannot be subtracted.  Moreover, your math in the example is faulty.  `hex(0x7612171 + 0x75612171 + 0x6553476F) == '0xe2158a51L'`.  Can you explain what you are actually trying to do?  Also, if you can produce some python  code that represents  your best effort to do what you describe, that will also help.

Comment: @jcd The example is correct if you discard the higher-order bits and treat these as unsigned values. See, e.g., http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0x75612171+%2B+0x75612171+%2B+0x6553476F (note the overflow).

Comment: How many additions or substractions can there be?

Comment: you can use windows calc to calculate these values which result in 50158A51

Comment: @Shai, if you want to clarify the question then you can edit it directly - you shouldn't post clarifications as answers. You really should rewrite the question and then delete your three answers (before people get annoyed!) :)

Comment: Thank you Scott, I have deleted my answers and edited my question again. (i am new with the site, guess i should read the rules of posting first)

English is not my native language so i maybe having trouble expressing my need.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for isn't possible. There will be infinite sequences of numbers that when added together will continue to produce the same result, modulo 2^32.

As a trivial example, say that your target number is 0x10000000 and the only hex values you allow are zero and one. Then the following sequences of numbers will result in 0x10000000:

```
0x1 + 0x1 + ... + 0x1 (0x10000000 times)  = 0x10000000 
0x1 + 0x1 + ... + 0x1 (0x110000000 times) = 0x10000000
0x1 + 0x1 + ... + 0x1 (0x210000000 times) = 0x10000000
```

and so on. Since you can continue adding 0x1's indefinitely, the algorithm can never terminate.

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply,

What i need to do using a python script is to find which combination will result this value : 0x50158A51 
i probably don't need all combinators just one from my char set
do you have another idea how can i achieve this ?

Comment: All combinations John provided are from your charset. Which one is not?

Comment: These are bad values (chars):


 \x80', '\x81', '\x82', '\x83', '\x84', '\x85', '\x86', '\x87', '\x88', '\x89', '\x8a', '\x8b', '\x8c', 
 '\x8d', '\x8e', '\x8f', '\x90', '\x91', '\x92', '\x93', '\x94', '\x95', '\x96', '\x97', '\x98', '\x99', 
 '\x9a', '\x9b', '\x9c', '\x9d', '\x9e', '\x9f', '\xa0', '\xa1', '\xa2', '\xa3', '\xa4', '\xa5', '\xa6',

Comment: \xa7', '\xa8', '\xa9', '\xaa', '\xab', '\xac', '\xad', '\xae', '\xaf', '\xb0', '\xb1', '\xb2', '\xb3', 
 '\xb4', '\xb5', '\xb6', '\xb7', '\xb8', '\xb9', '\xba', '\xbb', '\xbc', '\xbd', '\xbe', '\xbf', '\xc0', 
 '\xc1', '\xc2', '\xc3', '\xc4', '\xc5', '\xc6', '\xc7', '\xc8', '\xc9', '\xca', '\xcb', '\xcc', '\xcd', 
 '\xce', '\xcf', '\xd0', '\xd1', '\xd2', '\xd3', '\xd4', '\xd5', '\xd6', '\xd7', '\xd8', '\xd9', '\xda', 
 '\xdb', '\xdc', '\xdd', '\xde', '\xdf', '\xe0', '\xe1',

Comment: '\xe2', '\xe3', '\xe4', '\xe5', '\xe6', '\xe7', 
 '\xe8', '\xe9', '\xea', '\xeb', '\xec', '\xed', '\xee', '\xef', '\xf0', '\xf1', '\xf2', '\xf3', '\xf4', 
 '\xf5', '\xf6', '\xf7', '\xf8', '\xf9', '\xfa', '\xfb'

Comment: Half an hour ago you mentioned them as allowed. Has something happen since then?

Comment: I have an allowed set and non allowed set
i need to find the correct value within my allowed set
what iv'e included in the comment is the non allowed and whats in the question is the allowed set

Comment: lets try to simplify it :

lets say i have two values

104FE8EA

104FFFB4


i need to use subtraction (in three steps) in order to get from my first value to the second one 

i can use only hex values which are in my allowed set what will be the best way to archive this ?

Answer (score 1):

The following program for 0x50158A51 generates:

```
0x50157f51 + 0x00000b00 + 0x00000000 = 0x50158A51
```

for 0x1090F0FF it generates:

```
0x107f7f7f + 0x000011717f + 0x00000001 = 0x1090f0ff
```

where all "characters" in summands are from allowed set and not from disallowed set.

The program:

```
a=0x1090F0FF

a0=0
a1=0
a2=0
for n in range(3,-1,-1):
    a0<<=8;
    a1<<=8;
    a2<<=8;
    mask = 0xff<<(n*8)
    b=(a&mask)>>(n*8)
    if b > 2*0x7f:
        a0 += 0x7f
        a1 += 0x7f
        a2 += b - 2*0x7f
    elif b > 0x7f:
        a0 += 0x7f
        a1 += b - 0x7f
    else:
        a0 += b

print '%08x + %08x + %08x = %08x' % (a0, a1, a2, a0+a1+a2)
```